# Electric guitar grounding for safety

Tags: ground, grounding

As I understand it there are two reasons to ensure your electric guitar strings are connected to the common ground of the instrument.

1. To dissipate the EMF/RF interference created by the human holding the instrument, which reduces the noise level on the circuit
2. Safety

I understand the first. But the second reason I struggle with.

The oft-cited example...

> It's possible for the common or neutral side of the line to be out of phase with another power outlet or piece of gear. So, instead of the chassis and all common parts sitting at ground potential, they're at line potential relative to another piece of gear.

So far so good.

> If you're holding onto a guitar with "grounded" strings that are correctly grounded and walk up to the microphone with a "grounded" housing that really is at line potential it'll knock you flat on your ass. Done properly, it can even kill you.

So surely, in this situation the, the fact the the guitar strings are grounded makes touching the strings **more** dangerous. If the strings were not attached to the circuit you'd be safe?

So I'm thinking, if the strings are not grounded at all, the current might pass through my body and kill me that way, but at this point isn't the guitar irrelevant? So grounding the strings is pointless?

EDIT:
Looking at that link in the comments. The 3rd example in Kyle's link sees the path to ground from a faulty mic either going through the guitarist's feet OR through the earthed strings, but the latter is said to be more likely lethal. So the question remains, why ground the strings of that makes the legal path more likely?

Comment: You're not wrong - Guitar strings can be a shock hazard (and not just the microphone being a issue - Vintage tube amps can sometimes put high voltage on the strings in some failure modes).     Your strings can be "grounded" through a capacitor, so you don't have the shock hazard but still get the noise reduction.   You can't get away from the plug/jack being earth-ground however, so you can't completely remove any risk.    See here:  https://guitarnuts2.proboards.com/page/gn1-shock-hazards

Answer (score 3):

I think what's missing is an appreciation of why an electric guitar is the way it is.

The wiring of an electric guitar is basically UNCHANGED since the introduction of the iconic Les Paul and Tele/Stratocasters in the 50's.  So what you have is an instrument that's designed to work with the amplifiers of the day.  Virtually every electric guitar from every manufacturer today is wired basically the same way.

In 1955, the vast majority of power outlets did not have a 3-rd wire ground or even have one blade bigger than the other, so it was not only easy to get hot/neutral reversed, it was EXPECTED to happen 50% of the time.

To accommodate, a guitar amplifier chassis had a 'ground capacitor' switch such that the user could tie his instrument 'ground' (i.e. the plug/jack) to either of hot or neutral through a high-voltage capacitor.  The user would pick one of three positions (connect to either AC wire, or no connect at all) until the point of lowest hum was found.

This capacitor has since become known as the 'death cap', because a failure of it places live AC voltage on the strings.  (https://robrobinette.com/Death_Cap_and_Ground_Switch.htm)
It's just a crappy electrolytic, not a safety device, and such a scheme would *never* fly today.

Guitar amplifiers have had to keep up with changing UL standards etc.. so yes today you would find proper 3-prong plugs.  But people don't throw away old guitar amplifiers - Quite the opposite, they are coveted.

It would be super easy to design a 'perfect' guitar plug that was noise-free, high reliability, and safe. But that would be incompatible with the vast array of already existing gear.  Nobody would buy it and it'd be a market flop.

The thing is, guitar players are almost religious about keeping designs "vintage".  That's why the Les Paul/Strat/etc  have been in continuous production nearly unchanged for 70 years.  I challenge anybody to find any example of such a long-lived design in any other field.

Guitarists are strange creatures --- Tweak the design, they won't want it.  So it's the market that DEMANDS that guitars remain wired the way they are even though EE's know it's "wrong".

Comment: >It would be super easy to design a 'perfect' guitar plug that was noise-free, high reliability, and safe.   I'm not an electrical engineer, but this sounds wrong to me.  Aren't people basically big EMF antennae, picking up mains hum? The reason we touch the strings and buzz goes away isn't because the strings are being grounded through us, it's because we're being grounded through them isn't it?

Comment: Please point out where I'm going wrong if I am missing the point here; but I think that the reason we connect guitar strings to ground is because it's the easiest way of connecting _ourselves_ to ground. You said that it would be easy to design a perfect noise free "plug", but how would you eliminate hum without connecting the big bag of ionic fluid behind the guitar (the player) to ground?

Comment: @Some_Guy  Hi!   Unfortunately you have me at a disadvantage because I don't know your level of technical understanding (i.e. did you study physics, electromagnetics, etc...)  This stuff is pretty heady, and does not work as your intuition might suggest.   But I'll offer you two thoughts whilst I ponder how to better answer..   1)  When you have a wireless unit on your guitar, you have the exact same effect (touching strings makes the buzz go away).  However, in this case you're clearly not "grounded".

Comment: @Some_Guy   2)  Consider the XLR microphone.   There are TWO conductors inside the cable.  Each one carries an equal but opposite signal.   The shield is grounded, but neither of the signal wires are.  In a guitar, the shield IS a signal carrying wire  (it may be at 'zero voltage' but make no mistake, it carries the equal and opposite current that the center conductor does).  So an XLR-connected microphone (i.e. Shure SM58 etc..) would be "grounded"...  The whole case is connected to ground, yet there is no difference in 'buzz' whether you're touching the case or not.

Comment: physics including electromagnetics, but a while ago, and not enough that I don't have do so some serious headscratching with AC stuff that Electrical engineers live and breathe haha. Thanks for the response, off to do a bit of the aforementioned head-scratching!  And great point about wireless systems, I didn't actually know that happened. If that's the case then obviously it isn't working how I thought it was!

Answer (score 1):

> it's possible for the common or neutral side of the line to be out of phase with another power outlet or piece of gear. So, instead of the chassis and all common parts sitting at ground potential, they're at line potential relative to another piece of gear.

No professionally designed equipment will have that possibility unless multiple faults occur. The chassis and circuit ground is **always** isolated from both live and neutral through a good old-fashioned heavy-metal 50/60 Hz transformer or through the switching transformer of a more modern SMPS (switched-mode power-supply). We never assume that the live and neutral will be presented in a particular orientation.

Comment: That is how it should be. But really old guitar amps had 2-prong ungrounded mains plugs, and from one of the mains wires, there was a RF capacitor to chassis. Sometimes there was even a switch to select to which wire the chassis capacitor was connected to. At least one source : http://www.bustedgear.com/faq_Amp_shocks.htm

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of grounding electric guitar strings would be only to ground the guitarist in contact with them and thereby prevent ambient electrical noise, picked up by him/her, being passed on to the amplifier. Such a grounding would make for a quieter guitar and would neither complement nor compromise the safety of the guitarist, who would anyway be exposed to the danger of electric shock from the pickup/connector, microphone etc.

Safety to personnel would be ensured only by proper chassis grounding of all audio equipment through the 'third pin', using fuses of the right rating and ensuring 'line' and 'neutral' are connected to the right terminals in the plugs as well as receptacles.

Of course, the ultimate protection would be provided only by a Residual Current Device (RCD).

Answer (score 0):

A properly grounded system will improve safety, not make it more dangerous.  But that may not be easy in your situation.

> ...reasons to ensure your electric guitar strings are connected to the common ground of the instrument.

A lot comes down to what is meant by "common ground."  A safety ground provides a path to earth with no current running along it; any significant current running along your ground can and will negate its usefulness for safety.  **In particular, an AC neutral line should never be used for grounding.**  That neutral is the return path for the same current delivered by the hot line; if you connect yourself to neutral, you could become an alternate return path.

So in an ungrounded system, where only hot and neutral wires are available, then what is the answer for safety?  Either completely isolate from the power supply, or add a ground.  I nearly rewired a house to run a ground to ungrounded circuits; rewiring an amp is also possible.  It may not be cheap or easy, but the question is asking about safety.

> So surely, in this situation the, the fact the the guitar strings are grounded makes touching the strings more dangerous.

No!  Any number of things can ground you; you can argue about how current would enter/exit your body, but by that time all bets are off.  With proper grounding, in the guitar and in the microphone, your scenario would be prevented altogether.

You may decide that proper grounding is impractical for your situation, but that is your choice.  Grounding is still good practice.